# Waiting for functions to finish in C# .Net Core Partial Razor pages using fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a .Net Core Razor app with partial pages that get called by each function. Each partial is
linked to c-sharp code that runs some pretty heavy, time consuming SQL. After a cerain point,
I think the code finishes mostly based on logs, but the UI doesn't always update because
some of the SQL and processes going on can take like 30 minutes to an hour.

What is the best way to adjust this perhaps with `async` and `await`?

```
// function called by another partial page based on a button click event
// to start the process
function srartProcess() }

        fetch('processcode/?handler=StartProcessPartial')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then((result) => {

                if (result.trim().length == 0) {

                    // write some error output
                }
                else {

                    // do a bunch of UI display work

                    scrollBottom();

                    getStep2();
                }
            });
    }

    // Next partial and step
    function getStep2() {

        // more code with fetch and next step to getStep3() like above
        // which will continue with more functions for steps till it
        // gets to the end
}
```

Eventually the code should end and the UI should be updated.

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in the browser developer tools for any hints as to what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The commands in your server DBMS have timeouts. You may set them to 0, which will tell commands to wait for unlimited time.

```cs
command.CommandTimeout = 0; // command is of type DbCommand
```

Comment: Fetch _is_ "Ajax".

Comment: Then you shouldn't have problems with hanging UI. Or I don't understand the question? Is `fetch` synchronous or asynchronous version of Ajax, or can you provide a link to its docs?

Comment: Fetch is a modern alternative to XMLHttpRequest, which is the underlying technology behind jQuery's `ajax` method. It is asynchronous: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Let me ensure I understand the question correctly. You have an asynchronous request that calls an SQL query on the server. Query runs for half an hour or even more. Request doesn't block UI, but sometimes doesn't also update it. Right?

Comment: So Fetch is the more moden approach that the example you have in the api (the MDN docs show that). The issue is that I think the timeout occurs on the request if the query runs too long, which is probable something I need to look into on the backend server code like web.config, etc.

Comment: @cdub I see. Updated the answer, maybe it helps